# R: How to make transformations on subset of a subset fast (optimize or alternative to `ddply`)?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, plyr

I have a somewhat large data set (784,932 rows/items, 27,492 unique IDs). For each **Item** in each **ID**, I am trying to create a dummy variable equal to 1, if the difference between the dates is less than 60 secs.

Stylised data and code:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Item <- c(10,10,10,20,20,20,10,20,10,10,10,20)
Date <- c("19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:21","19/11/13 20:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 19:58:00")
df <- data.frame(ID, Item, Date)
df <- df[order(ID, Date), ]
df[, "Date"] = lapply(df["Date"],function(x){strptime(x, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")})

# less than 60 sec difference = 1 (first item set to 999 -> 0)
fnDummy <- function(date) { ifelse(c(999, diff(date))<60, 1, 0) }

library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID, Item), transform, Dummy=fnDummy(Date) )
```

Output:

```
   ID Item                Date Dummy
1   1   10 2013-11-19 18:58:00     0
2   1   10 2013-11-19 18:58:21     1
3   1   10 2013-11-19 20:58:00     0
4   1   20 2013-11-19 18:58:00     0
5   1   20 2013-11-19 18:58:00     1
6   1   20 2013-11-19 18:58:00     1
7   3   10 2013-11-19 18:58:00     0
8   3   10 2013-11-19 18:58:00     1
9   3   10 2013-11-19 18:58:00     1
10  3   10 2013-11-19 18:58:00     1
11  3   20 2013-11-19 18:58:00     0
12  3   20 2013-11-19 19:58:00     1
```

From the output you see that the first and second row have common ID and Item, and the difference in Date is only 21 secs, so the dummy is 1. The second and third row also have common ID and Item, but here the difference in date is much larger than 60 secs, so dummy is 0.

I managed to get the output I wanted, but the operation is slow. For 1000 rows it takes about 40 sec (see `system.time` results below). This corresponding to approx. 180 minutes for the entire data set (my computer runs out of memory and crashes long before this).

```
   user  system elapsed 
 36.485   3.328  39.800
```

How can I make this operation faster? Can i accomplish the same output using `data.table`, and is it faster?

Comment: Why do you use `ifelse`? `c(FALSE, diff(date) < 60)` should be sufficient. Use `as.integer` if you really need 0 and 1.

Comment: I realize you got your answer, but I'm a little baffled. The code in your question doesn't even run for me. I get an error on the `ddply` line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `data.table` as you suggest.  You'll have to convert your `POSIXlt` to `POSIXct` though:

```
library(data.table)
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)
DT <- as.data.table(df)

DT[, dummy_date := fnDummy(Date), by=c('ID', 'Item')]
```

However, a big part of the slowdown is probably in the `ifelse` function and you don't really need it since you're creating a boolean:

```
as.integer(c(FALSE, diff(date) < 60))
```

Comment: tiny note: I'd use `as.data.table(.)` instead of `data.table(.)`. The former is much faster.

Comment: @Arun correct!  But when answering questions three extra characters is too many...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now running the operation on the entire data set takes 14 sec. This is beautiful!

Comment: @bonna Glad to help.  For posterity, you might want to do a bit of code profiling.  `data.table` is much faster than `plyr`, but a big part of that speedup is coming from avoiding the `ifelse` also.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use dplyr to solve this problem:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3)
Item <- c(10,10,10,20,20,20,10,20,10,10,10,20)
Date <- c("19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:21","19/11/13 20:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 18:58:00","19/11/13 19:58:00")
df <- data.frame(ID, Item, Date = as.POSIXct(Date))

library(dplyr)

df %.% 
  group_by(ID, Item) %.%
  mutate(
    lagged = lag(Date, order_by = Date, default = 999), 
    dummy = Date - lagged < 60
  )
```

`lag()` effectively generalises `diff()` allowing you to specify an ordering value and a default for the first element.  (It also currently loses the attributes of the vector but that will be fixed in a future version. Track progress at https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/166)